# WebView is not rendering large inline html on Motorola G5 and G6, but works on iOS and other Android Phones. Anyone had this problem?

Tags: react-native

I have a WebView in React Native to render some html tables. It works on any device but not on Motorola G5 and G6 phones.

I'm using postMessage to get the table height to set on the WebView. On those Motorola phones my `document.body.innerHTML` (which I get using postMessage too) is empty when I render the full table on `source={{ html: theHtmlStringContainingTheTable }}`. If I just send an `<h1>with some text on it</h1>` it works perfectly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';
import webviewFunctionGenerator from 'utils/webview-function-generator';
import format from 'format-number';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
import { groupBy, map, mapObjIndexed, propEq, compose, values, join } from 'ramda';
import { toKebabCase } from 'ramda-extension';
import chilled from './chilled';
import frozen from './frozen';

const currency = format({ round: 0 });
const renderCountry = (country) => {
  const [name, abbr] = country.split('//');
  return `<img class="flag" src="http://minerva-trade.mazzafc.tech/img/flags/${toKebabCase(name)}.png">${abbr}`;
};

const renderRows = compose(
  join(''),
  values,
  mapObjIndexed(
    (item, country) => `
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        ${renderCountry(country)}
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="values">${item.frozen ? currency(item.frozen.price) : '-'}</td>
    <td class="values">${item.frozen ? currency(item.frozen.volume) : '-'}</td>
    <td class="values">${item.chilled ? currency(item.chilled.price) : '-'}</td>
    <td class="values">${item.chilled ? currency(item.chilled.volume) : '-'}</td>
  </tr>
`,
  ),
);

const template = ({ countries, t }) => `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    button,hr,input{overflow:visible}progress,sub,sup{vertical-align:baseline}[type=checkbox],[type=radio],legend{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}a{background-color:transparent}abbr[title]{border-bottom:none;text-decoration:underline;text-decoration:underline dotted}b,strong{font-weight:bolder}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}img{border-style:none}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;line-height:1.15;margin:0}button,select{text-transform:none}[type=button],[type=reset],[type=submit],button{-webkit-appearance:button}[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner,[type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner,button::-moz-focus-inner{border-style:none;padding:0}[type=button]:-moz-focusring,[type=reset]:-moz-focusring,[type=submit]:-moz-focusring,button:-moz-focusring{outline:ButtonText dotted 1px}fieldset{padding:.35em .75em .625em}legend{color:inherit;display:table;max-width:100%;white-space:normal}textarea{overflow:auto}[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}details{display:block}summary{display:list-item}[hidden],template{display:none}
      * {
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
      table {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border: 0;
        text-align: center;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
      }
      table td, table th {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
        padding: 5px 5px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        background-color: #F8FAFA;
        color: #565C63;
        vertical-align: middle;
        white-space: normal;
      }
      table tbody tr td {
        text-align: right;
      }

      table tbody tr td:first-of-type {
        text-align: center;
      }

      table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
        background-color: #FFF;
      }
      table tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
        background-color: #F8FAFA;
      }
      table td svg, table th svg {
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
      table th span {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      table th div,
      table td div {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .chilled {
        color: #4A90E2;
      }
      .frozen {
        color: #51B9D2;
      }
      .flag {
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
      .values {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">${t.source}</th>
            <th class="frozen" colspan="2">
              <div>
                ${frozen}
                ${t.frozen}
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="chilled" colspan="2">
              <div>
                ${chilled}
                ${t.chilled}
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="frozen">US$/ton.</td>
            <td class="frozen">Ton</td>
            <td class="chilled">US$/ton.</td>
            <td class="chilled">Ton</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          ${renderRows(countries)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
`;

/* eslint-disable */
const injectableJs = webviewFunctionGenerator(function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const table = document.querySelector('table');
    if (!table) {
      window.postMessage(
        JSON.stringify({
          error: true,
          message: 'Table does not exist!',
          html: document.body.innerHTML,
        }),
        '*',
      );
    }

    window.postMessage(
      JSON.stringify({
        tableHeight: table.clientHeight + 2,
        html: document.body.innerHTML,
      }),
      '*',
    );
  }, 500);
});
/* eslint-enable */

class PricingTable extends Component {
  state = { tableHeight: 0 };

  handleMessage = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const { error, message, tableHeight } = JSON.parse(nativeEvent.data);
    console.log('--data--', JSON.parse(nativeEvent.data));
    if (error) {
      console.error(`[TABLE RENDERER] Error: ${message}`);
    }
    if (tableHeight) {
      this.setState({ tableHeight });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    const countries = map(
      itens => ({
        chilled: itens.find(propEq('availability', 'chilled')),
        frozen: itens.find(propEq('availability', 'frozen')),
      }),
      groupBy(item => `${item.flag}//${item.country_abbreviation}`, this.props.pricings),
    );

    return (
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        bounces={false}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets
        injectedJavaScript={injectableJs}
        onMessage={this.handleMessage}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          height: this.state.tableHeight || 250,
          flex: 0,
        }}
        source={{
          html: template({
            countries,
            t: {
              chilled: t('common:chilled'),
              frozen: t('common:frozen'),
              source: t('common:source'),
            },
          }),
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default translate()(PricingTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577810/render-entire-vertical-content-of-react-native-webview). To hack around this, I specify a height in pixels, rather than the default of `'auto'` or alternatives like `flex: 1`, or `width: '100%'`. I have a similar question now.

I suspect the recommendation will be to stop using Expo if you already do, then use the recommended alternative, which is [React Native Webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview), then submit an issue if and only if the new React Native only (Expo free/ejected) app has the same problem with

I suspect this would be the advice from the React Native team of Facebook because WebView is [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview) and the new alternative, React Native Webview, can only be used with a normal React Native project. Read about React Native and [linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking) if that isn't clear already.